# Mapreduce job to HBase throws IOException: Pass a Delete or a Put

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, elastic-map-reduce

I am trying to output to a HBase table directly from my Mapper while using Hadoop2.4.0 with HBase0.94.18 on EMR.

I am getting a nasty `IOException: Pass a Delete or a Put` when executing the code below.

```
public class TestHBase {
  static class ImportMapper 
            extends Mapper<MyKey, MyValue, ImmutableBytesWritable, Writable> {
    private byte[] family = Bytes.toBytes("f");

    @Override
    public void map(MyKey key, MyValue value, Context context) {
      MyItem item = //do some stuff with key/value and create item
      byte[] rowKey = Bytes.toBytes(item.getKey());
      Put put = new Put(rowKey);
      for (String attr : Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a3")) {
        byte[] qualifier = Bytes.toBytes(attr);
        put.add(family, qualifier, Bytes.toBytes(item.get(attr)));
      }
      context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(rowKey), put);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    String input = args[0];
    String table = "table";
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "stuff");

    job.setJarByClass(ImportMapper.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(input));

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
            table,                  // output table
            null,                   // reducer class
            job);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Stacktrace**

Error: java.io.IOException: Pass a Delete or a Put at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:125) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:84) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:646) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:775) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162) Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Comment: Let's see the stack trace

Comment: In your provided code: `context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(rowKey), put);` its outside of the map method. Please fix it first because it doesn't match what the traceback is showing...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Ruben, it was a copy/paste mistake

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you can show the full stack trace, so that i can help you solve it easily. I've not executed your code. As far as i've seen your code, this could be the issue
`job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`

Mapper will be expecting your `put` object to write directly to Apache HBase.
You can increase the `setNumReduceTasks` OR If you see the API you can find its default value and comment it.

Comment: added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the stack trace.  Unfortunately you didn't include the code that threw the exception so I can't fully trace it for you.  Instead I did a little searching around and discovered a few things for you.

Your stack trace is similar to one in another SO question here:
[Pass a Delete or a Put error in hbase mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578963/pass-a-delete-or-a-put-error-in-hbase-mapreduce)

That one solved the issue by commenting out `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`

There is a similar SO question that had the same exception but couldn't solve the problem that way.  Instead it was having a problem with annotations:

["java.io.IOException: Pass a Delete or a Put" when reading HDFS and storing HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887050/java-io-ioexception-pass-a-delete-or-a-put-when-reading-hdfs-and-storing-hbas)

---

[Here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#mapreduce.example) are some good examples of how to write working code both with setNumReduceTasks at 0 and at 1 or more.

"51.2. HBase MapReduce Read/Write Example
The following is an example of using HBase both as a source and as a sink with MapReduce. This example will simply copy data from one table to another.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Job job = new Job(config,"ExampleReadWrite");
job.setJarByClass(MyReadWriteJob.class);    // class that contains mapper

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCaching(500);        // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);  // don't set to true for MR jobs
// set other scan attrs

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
  sourceTable,      // input table
  scan,             // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
  MyMapper.class,   // mapper class
  null,             // mapper output key
  null,             // mapper output value
  job);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
  targetTable,      // output table
  null,             // reducer class
  job);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
if (!b) {
    throw new IOException("error with job!");
}
```

This is the 1 or more example:

"51.4. HBase MapReduce Summary to HBase Example
The following example uses HBase as a MapReduce source and sink with a summarization step. This example will count the number of distinct instances of a value in a table and write those summarized counts in another table.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Job job = new Job(config,"ExampleSummary");
job.setJarByClass(MySummaryJob.class);     // class that contains mapper and reducer

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCaching(500);        // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);  // don't set to true for MR jobs
// set other scan attrs

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
  sourceTable,        // input table
  scan,               // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
  MyMapper.class,     // mapper class
  Text.class,         // mapper output key
  IntWritable.class,  // mapper output value
  job);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
  targetTable,        // output table
  MyTableReducer.class,    // reducer class
  job);
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);   // at least one, adjust as required

boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
if (!b) {
  throw new IOException("error with job!");
}
```

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#mapreduce.example

You seem to be more closely following the first example.  I wanted to show that sometimes there is a reason to set the number of reduce tasks to zero.